# Errors in Code (Need Help)

Tags: java, arrays, int, binary-search

I am trying to get this code to work, as it is essential for a project that I am currently working on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinarySearch
{
    int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x)
    {
        if (r>=l)
    {
        int mid = l + (r - l)/2;

        if (arr[mid] == x)
           return mid;

        if (arr[mid] > x)
           return binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x);

        return binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, x);
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    BinarySearch ob = new BinarySearch();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of inputs:");
        int i = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[] = new int[i];
    System.out.println("Enter array of inputs:");
        for(int j = 0;j < i; j++){
            arr[j] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("What number do you want the index from");
        int n = arr.length;
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        int result = ob.binarySearch(arr,0,n-1,x);
        if (result == -1)
            System.out.println("FAILURE");
        else
            System.out.println("Element found at index "+result + ".");
    }
}
```

I expect the result to be a normal input, in which the array can function.
The actual result I get is a Timeout error for "maybe having an endless loop."

Comment: Just a quick tip if you are having issues by implementing binary search yourself, there are overloaded static methods in Arrays class that perform binary search, take a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Printout you array as well as value of x in main().

Comment: There are issues with your `binary_search` method. It always returns the correct result, 3 and -1. Think about it. I had no "endless loop" error when running it.

Answer (score 1):

The binarySearch seems fine to me.

However binary search only works on an array sorted (by the comparison made).

A timeout indeed would mean that a loop or recursion would not end.
Considering

- case for recursion: l <= r
- given `int mid = l + (r - l)/2`
- hence l <= mid && mid <= r
- then `binarySearch(arr, l, mid-1, x);` works on `[l, <r]` (smaller)
- then `binarySearch(arr, mid+1, r, x);` works on `[>l, r]` (smaller)

the recursion will terminate.

Even on an unordered array (yielding garbage).

It looks more like the usage of the Scanner is problematic. I did not see  a clean usage with `hasNextLine`, `hasNextInt`, `nextInt` and `nextLine`.

The class [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) can provide a `sort` (and also has its own `binarySearch`).

---

***Code***

Not tested, and generally I do not use `Scanner` for `System.in`,
so probably can be written more succinct:

```
BinarySearch ob = new BinarySearch();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter number of inputs:");
if (sc.hasNextLine() && sc.hasNextInt()) {
    int i = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();

    int arr[] = new int[i];
    int n = arr.length;

    System.out.println("Enter array of inputs:");
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (sc.hasNextLine() && sc.hasNextInt()) {
            arr[j] = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
        } else {
            ...
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Important, binary search relies on the array being sorted:
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    System.out.printf("The sorted array is %s%n", Arrays.toString(arr));

    System.out.println("What number do you want the index from?");
    if (sc.hasNextLine() && sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        int result = ob.binarySearch(arr, 0, n-1, x);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but could you point out where and how to fix the aforementioned code? I'm having a little trouble on that.

Comment: Gave the corrected code. I did not use an IDE, so I hope it more or less doing what I think.